# How do I prevent NaN from appearing in my reports?

Tags: reporting-services

The following code returns a `NaN` in situations where there are no records. How do I prevent this from being displayed in the report? A 0 would be preferred.

```
=FormatNumber(
((
(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 1)) + 
(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 1)) + 
(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 1)) + 
(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 1)) + 
(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 1))
) / (
CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 1)) + 
CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 1)) + 
CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 1)) + 
CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 1)) + 
CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 1))
))
, 0)
```

Comment: What is the function NullSafeSplit() doing? Seems to me you could handle it there, by returning a 0 if nothing is done, or using an ISNULL() in the SQL.

Comment: NullSafeSplit returns a number or, if null, 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula below should get it. I haven't tested this, so I might be missing a parenthesis. The problem is likely coming from a divide by zero when all entries are null. This catches that and sets the divisor to 1 in that case.

```
=FormatNumber(
   (
      (Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 1)) + 
      (Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 1)) + 
      (Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 1)) + 
      (Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 1)) + 
      (Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 0) * Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 1))
   )
/
   (
       IIF((
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 1))
      ) = 0,
      1,
      (
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC1.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC2.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC3.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value, 1)) + 
   CInt(Code.NullSafeSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC5.Value, 1))
      )
      )
, 0)
```